# Javascript in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, data-set

I want to use a dynamic value inside querySelectorAll method but unable to use it.

```
let Product= event.target.dataset.item;
alert(Product);
let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="${Product}"]');
```

The above mentioned code is not working because it is not able to comprehend the value of product inside. **The alert is providing the correct value so the variable has correct data.

On hardcoding the value of the product its working fine

```
let Product= event.target.dataset.item;
 alert(Product);
 let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="OpenEdge"]');
```

added HTML:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-align_absolute-center">
                        <span>
                            <lightning-input class="slds-p-left_xx-large" type="checkbox" label="" data-item={product.MasterLabel} onchange={handleChange}>
                            </lightning-input>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-5 slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <template if:true={product.Product_Alerts__c}>
                        <span>
                            <lightning-input class="slds-p-left_xx-large" type="checkbox" data-id="{product.MasterLabel}"></lightning-input>
                            <lightning-input class="slds-p-left_xx-large" type="checkbox" data-id={product.MasterLabel}  ></lightning-input>
                        </span>
                    </template>
                    </div>
```

Is there any other way of using variable inside the method?

Comment: can you add markup as well?

Comment: didnot get what you meant to say exactly

Comment: Can you add html file as well, minimum viable code to reproduce, or if you can provide playground link it would be even better

Comment: Hi,I have added HTML snippet in the question itself.Please check

Comment: Try with this:-  let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="'+Product+'"]');

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sanket Kumar. It worked :)

Comment: @sanketkumar can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, Adding it.

Comment: @PriyankurChoudhury believe you need to use backticks instead of single quotes if you want it to work with your original code see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query the elements dynamically in Lightning Web Component, You need to change your markup as below:-

```
let Product= event.target.dataset.item;
alert(Product);
let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="'+Product+'"]');
```

It was the syntax that was wrong in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an alternative if the original syntax is something you want to use you'll just need to replace the single quotes **'** with backticks in order to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
Such as

```js
let Product = event.target.dataset.item;
alert(Product);
let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll(`[data-id="${Product}"]`);
```

should work as expected